# Catastrophic failure when executing linq query in Outlook Add-in

Tags: c#, linq, outlook-addin

I'm executing following code line to check the passed folder is already available in an existing list.

```
int foundIndex = folderList.FindIndex(search => search.Folder.EntryID == subFolder.EntryID);
```

When this line gets executed, an exception as

> "Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF
>   (E_UNEXPECTED))" is being thrown. This exception is thrown only when
>   I try to load the add-in through "Manage COM Add-ins" window by
>   clicking on "always enable this add-in" button.

Any idea why this is happening ? 
I'm using windows 8.1 and outlook 2016.

Comment: Are you sure that `folderList` is not null? Are you sure that for each item therein, `search.Folder` is not null?

Comment: Yes. it is not null.

Comment: Which call throws the exception? subFolder.EntryID? How many fodlers do you have in the list?

Comment: I do have like 16 folders.This problem does not happen at a normal outlook start. the code executes with no errors. This problem only occurs when I re-add the add-in via Manage Com Add-ins window. i found out that properties for the folder are not loaded. There is a error code property which has this this value  **-2147418113**